# Filter jcarousel content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I don't know if it's a bug or not, but here's my problem: I filter the jcarousel content using jquery. Everything goes ok until i start to use the next/prev buttons. On the default stage of filtering, buttons are working ok, but after i start to filter the content (images) the jcarousel start to work all crazy. For example, if i have 10 images in default state, showing 3 on stage, after filtering (let's say i have only 4 now) if i get to the last picture, the next button it's still enabled and i can scroll another 10-15px area even there is only blank space.

Images that are removed by the filter are going out by fadeOut animation.

I tried to call the jcarousel after every filtering action but i get the same result. In some cases, after i apply the filter, the prev btn. it's not enabled but i can scroll 100-200px area of blank space.

I tried to solve this issue for the last 3 days but i couldn't find the right solution.

Sorry for my english and thanks :-)

**Update:**

Here's my code maybe it will help understanding the issue:

```
$(".anim").jcarousel();
$("#menu ul li").click(function() {
    var flt = $('a', this).attr('rel');
    $('.anim li').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass(flt)) {
            $(this).fadeOut('normal');
        } else {
            $(this).fadeIn('normal');
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

The jCarousel structure (.anim) is:

```
<ul class="anim">
<li class="flt1"><img ... /></li>
<li class="flt1"><img ... /></li>
<li class="flt1"><img ... /></li>
<li class="flt2"><img ... /></li>
<li class="flt3"><img ... /></li>
</ul>
```

Where flt1..3 are my filters and the 'rel' value of menu links. The filtering works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell jCarousel how many items still remain.

For example, here is an anonymous function that I give to the config of jCarousel

```
function(carousel, state) {

                if (state != 'init') return;

                getProperties(function(properties) {
                    $.each(properties, function(i, property) {
                        carousel.add(i + 1, getPropertyHtml(property));
                    });

               carousel.size(properties.length);



                });

            }
```

Notice how at the end I have to set the size? What you need to do is find a suitable callback in the [configuration](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Configuration), and then set the new length of items.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alex. I've posted my code because i cant get it to work. Could you help me with this small issue?

Comment: One problem with setting the size when just hiding items in jCarousel is that if you resize the carousel (like when the browser resizes), it removes items with an index greater than the size. This can cause some big problems.